# Machine wide tracing with datadog and IIS and Datadog

Tags: datadog

I have the Data Dog agent running and Data Dog tracing set up machine-wide on my web server and all the services on the host are visible in Data Dog with the traces. The problem I am having is with the service names and environments. I have added a datadog.json file to the application root on the server but it does not pick up the values in there. I have tried restarting IIS according to the docs and restarting the app through IIS Manager but it still does not get my tags or service names.

I have not installed the nuget packages yet and was hoping this would be possible without that.

Is it possible to setup Data Dogs [Universal Service Tagging](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/dotnet-core/?tab=jsonfile) without installing the nuget packages? And if so how can I get it working